# In postgres, how can I select the top X rows containing the top Y occurances of the many column in a many-to-one relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The question was not very clear, but a table will help explain it. Say I have a table `posts` like the one below, which maps user ID's to messages they post on a social media platform, in a many to one relationship.

| user_id | post_message |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | "some post from user one" |
| user_1 | "another post from user one" |
| user_2 | "random post from user two" |
| user_2 | "one more post from user two" |
| user_3 | "user three's first post" |
| user_3 | "user three's second post" |

My goal is to select the top 2 users along with all their posts. The result of my query would be:

| user_id | post_message |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | "some post from user one" |
| user_1 | "another post from user one" |
| user_2 | "random post from user two" |
| user_2 | "one more post from user two" |

The best way that I can think of doing this is with the following query `SELECT * FROM posts as a INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM posts ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 2) as b ON a.user_id = b.user_id;`

Is there a more efficient way of writing this query? Maybe something that doesn't require an inner join?

Comment: How do you define "Top 2"?

Comment: Ordered by user id, all posts created by the top X unique users.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dense_rank`

```
select user_id, post_message
from (
  select user_id, post_message, dense_rank() over( order by  user_id) r
  from posts
) t
where r<=2
```